# H14 Heroku "No web processes running" for Flask, Python

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I wrote a small site using Python and the Heroku web framework. Faced a problem that the application did not work, however, when running locally (through my terminal) everything works.
Logs say the following:

`2020-05-20T06:19:35.538634+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=reviewssystem.herokuapp.com request_id=00dd8d00-f6b0-471b-bab7-65d065c60025 fwd="109.229.183.36" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

I tryed to use `heroku ps:scale web=1` and get this:

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

`heroku ps` output: `No dynos on ⬢ reviewssystem`

Procfile: `web: gunicorn app:app`. I also tryed use `web: python app.py` and it didn't helped.

requirements.txt:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.16
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Build log:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 47.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v8
       https://reviewssystem.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

So, what I should to do for fix it?

Comment: Can you check settings if the heroku/python buildpack is there? And also paste a gist of your build log.

Comment: Pasted a build log. And I guess i have heroku/python buildpack

Comment: Please paste your Procfile

Comment: I already pasted it in the question - web: gunicorn app:app

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But the error is `Procfile declares types -> (none)`. So I want to double check.

Comment: Another thing to check is this: https://prnt.sc/snadvj

The switch has to be on.

Comment: I have written there that "This app has no process types yet"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214634/discussion-between-h4cktivist-and-mikhail-beliansky).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `Procfile` and re-creating it. Git for some reason did not recognize this `Procfile` and named it something like `Pro/143/file` (I don't know why).

So, if you encounter such a problem, try to re-create your `Procfile.` Anyway, it helps for me.

P.S I left the contents of the file as before: `web: gunicorn app:app`.

As you can see, everything works:
[image]

Comment: So the problem was with Procfile, just as I suggested.